# How to slow down scroll speed of dynamic page using selenium webdriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using following code to scroll dynamic page using python selenium webdriver, which is rendered by JS. I am able to scroll but problem is scroll speed is too fast and most of the elements of page are not getting loaded, which I want to **scrape**. Is there any way to slow down scroll speed.

```
scrl_time = 5
#get scroll height
scrl_hght = browser.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')
for i in range(3):
    #scrol to bottom page
    browser.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')
    #wait to load page
    time.sleep(scrl_time)
    #calculate scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = browser.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')
    if new_height == scrl_hght:
        break
    scrl_hght=new_height
```

Comment: for me, just increasing the scrl_time did the trick, But I only increased it from 2 to 3. Yours is 5 and still not enough to slow down? you can also try to increment the sleep time every N times the scraper fails to find elements, it works for me, if you want i can post a full answer about it.

Comment: increasing sleep time was not solution, as scroll to the end of page was happening too quickly and then resting there for 5 seconds, which didn't help. there could be many ways but I found a fix that resolved my problem. I added couple of leaps to my scroll rather than single leap, and that helped to load the page. Thanks.

Comment: you might need to loop `browser.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')` as it will sort of teleport into the final location